# How to get the total amount of holders of a BSC token?

Tags: python, web-scraping, cryptocurrency, binance-smart-chain

How do I get the total amount of holders of a BSC token? I could not find an API that retrieves this information.

The only possible way I have found is to scrape BscScan. For example: https://bscscan.com/token/0x42981d0bfbaf196529376ee702f2a9eb9092fcb5

However, every time I try this BscScan blocks me with a CloudFlare's anti-scrape system.

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: did you find a solution ?